# Image pop up from a text file in python

Tags: python, image, url, popup

I have a text file, where I have multiple image links. I can read that file line by line in Python as hyperlinks. But I am trying to use those links as a pop-up when I will click the link, not to open in a different window. Any tools or any library that I can use?

[image]

Comment: is this in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Hello @JonSG, It is in google colab.

Comment: rather than print the raw url, can you print a complete `a` tag including the `target` attribute?

Comment: @jonson, You can use tkinter and PIL library in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JavaScript popup link as follows:

```html
<a href="some url" target="popup" onclick="window.open('some url','popup','width=w,height=h'); return false;">
some url
</a>
```

In Google Colab you can display HTML from Python using:

```
IPython.display.display(HTML(html content))
```

So you process the file and add the corresponding html to a result variable for each line, then display the full contents.

MCVE:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

links = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lOtO.png", "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/helium_reserve.png", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPtbt.jpg"]

def makepopup(link):
  return f"""<a href="{link}" target="popup" onclick="window.open('{link}','popup','width=600,height=200'); return false;">{link}</a><br>"""

linklist = ""
for link in links:
  linklist += makepopup(link) + "\n"

display(HTML(linklist))
```

Result (screenshot after clicking the first link):
[image]

Note that you do need to provide some fixed width and height, otherwise the popup is just full screen.

Comment: Thank you for your guideline. It was really helpful for me.